# How to tell JSDoc that a method returns an object containing a class type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, ts-check

I have a Node.js function to create an Express server.

I've added `//@ts-check` to the file so that VSCode lints and type-checks everything.

What is the correct way to document this `createServer` function?

I want to show that it returns a Promise which resolves an object containing an Express instance (`app`), and the Number (`port`)

If this is an anti-pattern, that would be nice to know as well.

```
//@ts-check
const express = require('express');

/**
 * @param {Number} port
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function createServer(port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const app = express();
        server = app.listen(port, () => {
            resolve({app, port});
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I always use `Promise<Resolving object type>`

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good pattern to me. Adding middlewares after listen may not work as expected, depending on how you use it. I see no good reason to resolve with `{app, port}`. Usually you need only `app`. What's the purpose of `port`? You already have it in place where you call `createServer`.

Comment: @estus Thanks for pointing that out. I agree that if I have `port` as an input, then why add it as an output. It's mainly reduce repeated code in my unit tests, but i appreciate you pointing that out

Comment: I guess tests are virtually the only place where you may need to create servers in batch. But keep in mind that it's beneficial to keep server instantiation and listening separately. E.g. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest works best with unlistened Express instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiles for me:

```
//@ts-check
const express = require('express');

/**
 * @param {Number} port
 * @returns {Promise<{app: import("express").Express, port: number}>}
 */
function createServer(port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const app = express();
        const server = app.listen(port, () => {
            resolve({app, port});
        });
    });
}
```

See [the documentation page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript) for more information.

Comment: Love this import in the comment! (y)
Thank you!